# control an object from different .h on main window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

my application is window based application in objective-c
I have **appdelegate** file (.h and .m) and **controller** (.h and .m)
the program load the window view from the **appdelegate** file and shows the objects (slider, labels) which defined in **controller** so: 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in **appdelegate** 
the label in **controller**
all i need to know how can i get control on the label from that function.

Answer (score 2):

If you establish the label as a property with getter and setter methods:

in controller.h:

```
{
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

in controller.m:

```
@synthesize label;
```

Then you can simply call the `label` from an instantiation of `controller`:

```
[controller.label setText:@"For example, you can set the text"];
```

Comment: in general how can i set the value of an object in the main window if it's not defined in the same appdelegate file?

Comment: thanks for your response but it didn't work nothing shown in the screen after running the project this is the code :- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 myControl=[[Controller alloc]init];
 
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 
 [myControl.label setText:@"Become Active"];
 
 return YES;
}

Comment: @Mudar: In the code snippet, you never added the `myControl.view` to the `window`. You need to do this in order for `myControl` to show up.

Comment: dear friend, your help is greatly appreciated, how to add myControl.view if my controller class is type NSObject should i change it to UIView? and where to add that is it like [window addSubview:myController.view];?

Comment: You're controller should be a subclass of `UIViewController`. Then, you can add `[window addSubview:myController.view];` to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: dear PengOne, thanks for your help, it worked the way you said. my goal was to find a way to control the view in the current situation but it seems not to be workable. in my search i fount something called _topLevelNibObjects in the UIApplication.h do you know how to get this array's objects ?

Comment: dear PageOne, Thanks a lot for your help, i found that the way I was looking is incorrect and the object is pushed to the view and no handle for it any more so if i want to get an access to it i have to define it in the .h file and alloc it in .m file then keep it retained till i finish using it. this concept i missed in my research before. this answer for anybody having my same problem.